# series convergent problem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{n-1}\sin\frac{a}{n}} \qquad  (a>0)$ convergent

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\frac{a}{n})$ is monotonically decreasing towards 0. Therefore the series is a Leibniz series therefore converges.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that this is an alternating series.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin{\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)}=0$$

What does this tell us about the convergence/divergence of the series?